# Run from the command line in visual studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, csc

I'm trying to execute a program using run from the command line ,my program takes 4 arguments and it connect to a web service .

so i execute this simple command `csc Program.cs`

I'm getting this error : `error cs0234 The type or namespace Srd doesn't exist`

But Srd is the name of Web reference.
i tried this

`csc /r:Web Reference/Srd Program.cs`

But the problem persists.

So how to add it in the command line

Comment: ...if you're going to try compiling via the command line, it is probably best that you understand the compilation process.

Comment: This post is a touch confusing, are you saying your program is trying to compile program.cs or that program.cs is your program and it needs compiling? Answer by clarifying your question to those reading it cold.